# How can I set boundaries for a custom Android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to get a region of the Android camera demarcated for a picture (as in the image below). I want only the marked area to appear in the picture.

1. How can I create a custom camera that shows the marked region when I open the camera (within my app)?
2. How can I take a picture only of the marked area?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SurfaceView` takes more space than you inner-rectangle, you'll have to crop the obtained image.

Use `Bitmap.createBitmap()`:

> Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the original bitmap.

Pass it a bitmap, and define the rectangle from which the new bitmap will be created:

```
// Take 42 pixels off 4 sides
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, 42, 42, originalBmp.getWidth() - 42, originalBmp.getHeight() - 42);
```